# WatiN - How to handle auto complete popup?

Tags: .net, asp.net, nunit, watin

We're having an intermittent problem that occurs when running certain integration tests on our continuious integration server..

For some reason, every now and then, we get an autocomplete popup that causes a timeout and ultimately a build failure.

Is there an eloquent way to detect the popup and click through it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the IE autocomplete fonction, do you really need it.

You could deactive the function in the browser option.

Comment: Disabling the functionality isn't really an option, as we have no real control over the machine that is running the integration tests.